# Save form data in client with unstable internet connection

Tags: javascript, python, bottle, forms, http-post

I have a piece of open source software written in python which uses the bottle web server to display forms in a web browser. The form data are send via "method = post" to the web server. Until now the server process is running on the same (PC) host as the browser, so there is no issue with the internet connection.

Now I have to rewrite this software so that it can be used on mobile devices, with the server somewhere in the internet. The environment in which data entry is to take place will be such that an unstable or lost internet connection is likely. So I have to have provisions for the case that the website containing the form is loaded first (in the office via WLAN, say), then data entry takes place (in the "field") and during data entry, internet connection is lost, so that saving data to the server won't work. In this case it would be great to be able to save the form data locally, in order to send the post-request later on. (Probably it won't be possible to keep the website open all the time until this is possible. The latest when battery goes low, I'd run into problems.)

Probably I'm not the first with this problem, so my question is: is there a "standard" (or well tested) solution for the task to buffer form data on the client side for the case when a post-request is not answered, and send the same request later on? If not, how would you go about to solve this issue? In particular, I see the following (sub-)problems:

1. How to detect (on the client side) that a post request failed? Probably some kind of timeout mechanism in javascript would have to be employed, but how?
2. How to save data? My first idea would be to save data to a cookie using javascript. Do I overlook something here?
3. How to send data back later on?

I'm sufficiently proficient in python to dare this project, but rather new to web technologies, so please excuse if some part of the question is rather stupid. In this case, I'd be grateful to be told so... (... with a hint on how to ask a better question.)

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Your question is quite broad and hard to answer. But you are looking for offline support in browser. There are many tutorials on the net, one still relevant article is https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/whats-offline/.

Comment: "Offline support" is a very useful trigger. I'm gonna see how far the tutorials get me, and come back here with a more specific question if necessary. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer based on (sub-)problems:

---

> How to detect (on the client side) that a post request failed? Probably some kind of timeout mechanism in javascript would have to be employed, but how?

#### To detect if request failed

1. Only send status code 200 if you received data and it's saved to backend!
2. Don't send 200 if there is an error! *(use error status code like 5xx or 4xx)*
3. There is a `timeout` option in jquery to cancel the request if it takes more than given time to complete
4. When failed, Save data to localStorage

If you are not using jquery, I guess you can do something similar using `fetch` in **vanilla javascript** (Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to know more about `fetch`)

```
$.ajax({
    timeout: 3000 // sets timeout to 3 seconds
}).done(function () {
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
    var _local = localStorage.getItem('data-saved'); //get localStorage data
    _local.push({"key": "value"}) // Append JSON based Form data
    localStorage.setItem('data-saved', JSON.stringify(_local)); // Update localStorage
});
```

---

> How to save data? My first idea would be to save data to a cookie using javascript. Do I overlook something here?

### Save data using `localStorage`

In LocalStorage, you can't store JSON however, you can save using `JSON.stringify` and load back using `JSON.parse`

```
// Get data
var get_local_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data-saved'));
// Update Data
get_local_data.append({"Name": "value", "age": 10})
// Update localStorage
localStorage.setItem('data-saved', JSON.stringify(get_local_data));
```

---

> How to send data back later on?

#### Sending data back using `setTimeout` method in javascript

Check continuously if there is any data in localStorage's key. If any send an ajax request to back-end!

```
// Run in each 5 Sec
setTimeout(function () {
    // Check if we have any failed data
    var get_local_data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data-saved'));
    if(get_local_data.length > 0){
        //Make a ajax request
        //Update localStorage if success (You need to remove the data from the localStorage), 
        //Ignored failed case
    }    
}, 5000);
```